# Replace IIS Express certificate with sha-256 certificate

Tags: https, iis-express, sha

Since sha-1 is no longer secure and Google Chrome now shows an [error](http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.com/2014/09/gradually-sunsetting-sha-1.html) when using https with a sha1 certificate, how do I replace the IIS Express certificate with a sha-256 self-signed certificate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In mmc's [Certificate plug in](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd632619.aspx), add your new certificate to local computer's Personal store.
2. At command prompt, use [`netsh http`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733791%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to change certificate mapping from the old one to your new one.

You might also try out Jexus Manager for IIS Express, which simplifies the task to a few clicks,

https://jexus.codeplex.com/releases/view/138373

https://www.jexusmanager.com/en/latest/tutorials/self-signed.html

[image: Self signed]